# How do invoke the Paypal IPN using the REST API c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk

I am having problems invoking the PayPal IPN. I dont know which URL to give or which URL i am meant to give. I have looked all over the internet for help but there does not seem to be anything available hence why i have come here.

So firstly, i have the PaymentWithPaypal Action

```
public ActionResult PaymentWithPaypal(int? id, Page page)
    {  
        //getting the apiContext as earlier
        APIContext apiContext = Models.Configuration.GetAPIContext();

        try
        {        
            string payerId = Request.Params["PayerID"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(payerId))
            {

                string baseURI = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + "/ControllerName/PaymentWithPayPal?";


                var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                //CreatePayment function gives us the payment approval url

                //on which payer is redirected for paypal acccount payment
                var createdPayment = this.CreatePayment(apiContext, baseURI + "guid=" + guid);

                //get links returned from paypal in response to Create function call

                var links = createdPayment.links.GetEnumerator();

                string paypalRedirectUrl = null;

                while (links.MoveNext())
                {
                    Links lnk = links.Current;

                    if (lnk.rel.ToLower().Trim().Equals("approval_url"))
                    {
                        //saving the payapalredirect URL to which user will be redirected for payment
                        paypalRedirectUrl = lnk.href;
                    }
                }

                // saving the paymentID in the key guid
                Session.Add(guid, createdPayment.id);

                return Redirect(paypalRedirectUrl);
            }
            else
            {

                // This section is executed when we have received all the payments parameters

                // from the previous call to the function Create

                // Executing a payment

                var guid = Request.Params["guid"];

                var executedPayment = ExecutePayment(apiContext, payerId, Session[guid] as string);

                if (executedPayment.state.ToLower() != "approved")
                {
                    return View("FailureView");
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log("Error" + ex.Message);
            return View("FailureView");
        }
        return View("SuccessView");
    }
```

This is the code for the IPN.

```
[HttpPost]
    public HttpStatusCodeResult Receive()
    {
        //Store the IPN received from PayPal
        LogRequest(Request);

        //Fire and forget verification task
        Task.Run(() => VerifyTask(Request));

        //Reply back a 200 code
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    }

    private void VerifyTask(HttpRequestBase ipnRequest)
    {
        var verificationResponse = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            var verificationRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");

            //Set values for the verification request
            verificationRequest.Method = "POST";
            verificationRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            var param = Request.BinaryRead(ipnRequest.ContentLength);
            var strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);

            //Add cmd=_notify-validate to the payload
            strRequest = "cmd=_notify-validate&" + strRequest;
            verificationRequest.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

            //Attach payload to the verification request
            var streamOut = new StreamWriter(verificationRequest.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
            streamOut.Write(strRequest);
            streamOut.Close();

            //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
            var streamIn = new StreamReader(verificationRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            verificationResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
            streamIn.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Logger.Log("Error" + exception.Message);
            //Capture exception for manual investigation
        }

        ProcessVerificationResponse(verificationResponse);

    }


    private void LogRequest(HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        // Persist the request values into a database or temporary data store
    }

    private void ProcessVerificationResponse(string verificationResponse)
    {
        if (verificationResponse.Equals("VERIFIED"))
        {
            Logger.Log("Verified");
            // check that Payment_status=Completed
            // check that Txn_id has not been previously processed
            // check that Receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
            // check that Payment_amount/Payment_currency are correct
            // process payment
        }
        else if (verificationResponse.Equals("INVALID"))
        {
            Logger.Log(verificationResponse);
        }
        else
        {
            //Log error
        }
    }
```

Now to clear things up. My understanding of the IPN is that when a customer purchases an item, the SELLER will get an email telling them that they have sold a product and then from this you can access transactionId etc.

So in my view i have a form with a button that looks like this.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Buy Now", "PaymentWithPaypal", new { Id = Model.Id, @class = "" })
```

This is what takes the customer to paypal where they can then purchase but this is where i am stuck because im not sure how to call the IPN or if it needs its own view.

ANY CLARITY WOULD BE OF MUCH HELP AT THIS MOMENT IN TIME.

Comment: Is there any special reason for SHOUTING?

Comment: AFAIK IPN does not send any email either to seller nor customer, it is just a method of getting a feed of completed payment which then you can update your order status on your website using the information in the IPN message.

Comment: @Anaheim so does that mean the seller and customer will get an email when a purchase is made?

Comment: The email both party should get (seller and buyer) but this however does nothing to do with IPN.

Comment: check out the docs from paypal site https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

Answer (score 0):

One way is to put this under PayPal account settings. Once you click on your "App", below it you see the redirect url option. Just add it there. Paypal .net sdk doesn't have the option to pass `notify_url`. All other modes have. Because, paypal.net sdk accepts `return_url` which is usually the same action method as also mentioned in your code.

Check this:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/#

In case you want to achieve real time events, you need to use webhooks now. Documentation below:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/wiki/Webhook-Event-Validation